# DRF image url not returning on filtering

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

If I write some queries in `serializers` or `views` and it does not return url of image, instead it returns `/media/image.jpg` why is that?

for example

```
class GetWishlistSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    review = SerializerMethodField()
    product = CustomForeignKeyField(required=False, queryset=Product.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = WishList
        fields = ['id', 'user','product', 'review']

    def get_review(self, obj):
        return Review.objects.filter(product_id=obj.product_id).count()
```

this is not returning url of image but `/media/product_images/image.png`

How filter effects on image url?

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class ProductImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images', null=True)
```

i want my output some like this

```
"category":"category",
"images":[ 
   { 
      "id":1,
      "product":1,
      "image":"http://localhost:8000/media/products/2019/12/14/b_dfdfd_RT-53_K6340SL1.jpg"
   },
   { 
      "id":2,
      "product":1,
      "image":"http://localhost:8000/media/products/2019/12/14/dsdsfxd_RT-53_K6340SL2.jpg"
   }
]
```

here is the model, without filtering everything works fine but with it does not work.

how do I return url of image?

Comment: question was clear. what do you want exactly?

Comment: how to return url of image?

Comment: no `image` field in your  serializer

Comment: there is. it is in product as you can see from the model `ProductImage`

Comment: you don't get it that way. share an example how you want your output looks like

Comment: you can have a look

Answer (score 0):

This will do the magic. I didn't test it. but it should work.

```
class ProductImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(source='image.url', use_url=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ProductImage
        fields = ['id', 'product', 'image']


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.CharField(source='category.name')
    images = ProductImageSerializer(source='images', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['category', 'images']
```

Comment: thanks for the answer it is already existed in my serializer. If you noticed I am not using this in ProductSerializer I want to use it GetWishlistSerializer I mean when user wants to add wishlist it should return all data of product. it is returning all data as well as image but images are not coming with urls it returns like `/media/products/blablabla`. was it clear?

Comment: try `image = serializers.ImageField(source='image.url', use_url=True)`

Comment: in `ProductImageSerializer` should use?

Comment: yes I used but it returned this `"images": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "product": 1,
                "image": null
            }
]`

Comment: you should have an image associated with the record.

Comment: `ProductImage` is table where all images are stored when product is added and also image is added. There are images in the table